# Не подключается клиентская часть socket.io

Tags: javascript, socket.io

Серверная часть работает, пытаюсь вивести клиенскую, ошибок нет но `console.log('Client connect')` не виводится. Помогите решить, и обясните почему.
Файл `index.html`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
       <h1>wellcome</h1>
        <script src= "socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            const socket = io()
            socket.on('connection', () => {
                console.log('Client connect')
            })
        </script>
        <textarea name="name" rows="8" cols="40"></textarea>
        <p></p>
        <input type="text" name="text" size="20">
        <button type="button" name="button">Отправить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл `server.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const socketIO = require('socket.io')
const path = require('path')
const http = require('http')

const clientPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
const io = socketIO(server)


io.on('connection', () => {
    console.log('IO Connection')
})

app.use(express.static(clientPath))

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server has been started on port ' + port)
})
```

Comment: Наименование ивента там чуть другое: https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#Event-%E2%80%98connect%E2%80%99

Comment: Спассибо большое)